# Finding the least number of dots to add into a 10x10 grid

Tags: combinatorics, arithmetic, problem-solving

I have a 10x10 grid where are some dots.[image]

What is the least number of dots that I need to add in order to

1. have 3 dots in every row and column
2. have odd number of dots in every row and column
3. have even number of dots in every row and odd number of dots in every column
4. have a dot in two of every dotted square's neighbour squares

*(neighbour squares are squares that have the same side, each non-border squares have 4 neighbour squares)*

I'm sure these questions can be answered without brute-forcing but how?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: For (1) do you mean *exactly* three dots or *at least* three dots? For (4) what are the two neighbor squares of a square (I count four or eight for each non-border square)? For (3) is zero considered to be an even number? For (2) an easy answer is eight, putting a dot in each square down the main diagonal.

Comment: For (1) I naturally mean exactly three dots.But for every answer, I need the least number of dots to add in order to complete that particular question. Like I said for (4), neighbour squares are squares that have the same side, so each non-border square has four neighbour squares. Your answer for (2) is not right? Then I still have some rows and columns where are even number of dots.

Comment: Oops, for (2) I meant ten, putting a dot in each square down the main diagonal. (I was thinking of a chessboard, of size eight.) You should correct your question (4) if there are more than two neighbor squares. Or do you mean that two of the four neighbor squares should have a dot?

Comment: Well, already if you add the second dot, there are an even number of dots in the second column. And yes, I mean two of the four.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For parts 1-3 I used a greedy algorithm favoring rows over columns. This is a little bit different than using brute force because rather than checking all possible legal arrangement of dots, I choose a strategy that I hoped would work(namely a greedy strategy). This is a common thing to try, because greedy algorithms tend to be easy to execute and are great for establishing an upper bound(if the algorithm halts on a solution.) In these cases, the lower bound was also easy to establish once I saw the finished products, and fortunately they matched the upper bound given by my greedy algorithm.

I should mention that my greedy algorithm for part 2 technically halted on a non-solution since once I added the third dot every row was odd, so I was unable to add a fourth dot without messing that up. Fortunately, it wasn't hard to figure out that I only needed two more dots and if I put them in the same row, it will preserve the parity.

Note: there are plenty of situations where greedy algorithms will not yield the optimal solution or even a solution, but due to their ease of use, they are a natural tool to try when you don't have other strategies in mind.

(1)
[image: solution to (1)]

(2)
[image: solution to (2)]

(3)
[image: solution to (3)]

For (1) we know this is best because there are 30 total dots. For (2) this is best because there were five columns of even parity, so minimally five dots were needed. For (3) this is best because there were seven rows of odd parity, so we know at least seven dots needed to be added.

For part (4) if I understand your constraints correctly, I believe that the following is a minimal solution with the addition of 24 dots. I leave this without proof since it would be tedious, but the result relies on the fact that each dot must be part of either a cycle or a path between two cycles.

[image: solution to (4)]

Comment: The OP asked if "these questions can be answered without brute-forcing but how?" Can you go into more detail on how you answered #1 and explain how that is not "brute-forcing"? By the way, nice answers for #1!

Comment: @RoryDaulton, I will try to add a bit more detail.

Comment: Thank you so much! Marked as the right answer. Can you tell me, did you use programming for this problem?

Comment: If by "programming" you mean the assistance of a computer, no. I did it by hand. If by "programming" you mean the use of an algorithm? Then yes.

Comment: @JohnDoe to understand what my thinking was, I would ask "does the first row have a desired number of dots?" If yes, I move on to the second row and ask again. If no, I ask "what is the first column that doesn't have the desired number of dots and doesn't have a dot in the current row." Once I find such a column, I add a dot, then start over. This algorithm halts if either I complete all of the row requirements or if I cannot find a column with the desired properties. This is called a greedy algorithm because I solve the problem only considering the current row rather than the whole grid.

Comment: I meant programming with the assistance of a computer. Thank you for expanding my knowledge.